# Trigger on SQL Server Table to insert items in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint

We have a custom SQL Server table with some data. Whenever a record gets created in this table, we need to update a sharepoint list with the information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [CLR Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093.aspx) and write your list update code in there using the [SharePoint Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx) library

Comment: Thanks Ali for your suggestion. We already have an existing sharepoint list which we need to update. Does your suggestion ask for creating and maintaining a new sharepoint list. Thanks.

Comment: Creating yes, maintaining no. Do the list and the table have the same data? An external list will have all the data from the SQL table so you just have to maintain the SQL table which I'm assuming already happens

Comment: The list has more data than the custom table. The custom table is another source of entry for the sharepoint list. This is an existing sharepoint list, so I'm somehow looking for the best option to add the data in the custom table to this existing sharepoint list. Thanks.

Comment: Does all of the data in the list come from the DB? Can you create a view then use that for an external list? If not maybe try a CLR Trigger